# How to load ItemsSource before setting SelectedItem in ListView?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, itemssource, selectedvalue

I have a `MVVM` page that contains a `ListView`. I bind `ItemSource` and `SelectedValue`, but first time it calls converter for `SelectedValue` then loads `ItemSource`.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewSurahs"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
              FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="4"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="ID"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource CurrentInfo},
                                      Path=Instance.ID,Mode=OneWay}"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False" />
```

because of that I lose `SelectedItem` and no Items get selected. what should I do to load `ItemsSource` first?

Comment: If I understand that correctly: The first time the `IValueConverter` is called you get `null` passed to convert?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann : the first time converter is called it returns for example 5 but because ItemSource doesn't exist it doesn't select anything and SelectedItem is Null

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you can try to type your ItemsSource in codebehind. You have to add an UserLoaded property in your xaml file to do this. But maybe we need to see your codebehind and viewmodel. Anyway you should try to change your **SelectedValue** binding mode **OneWay** to the **TwoWay**.

After that you should watch your binding style. You have to complete most of your development progress in your *viewmodel*, and after that you could just call your viewmodel from your xaml codebehind (.cs) with *get-set*. So, you will have a very clean binding structure.

In this way you can type as follows instead of yours,

```
    SelectedValue="{Binding Model.BlaBla, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

in here **Model** is defined and called in your codebehind of xaml file (.cs). For example in top of your **public sealed partial class**

```
    public YourViewModelName Model { get; set; }
```

and in the same file **public YourXamlName()**

```
    Model = new YourViewModelName();
```

It is a quickly answer and I am not sure. But you should give a shot.

Good luck.