# setting delay to update target in Binding in UWP

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

I bind `SelectedValue` of my ListView and this binding used converter.
I want that `ConvertBack` method be executed after a delay, it seems to be easy in `WPF` but not in `UWP`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Based on [your last case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741754/how-to-load-itemssource-before-setting-selecteditem-in-listview), you key problem is still setting a selected item when when first time the items are loaded, is that OK for your scenario if using `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT: No it is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to delay in your `ConvertBack`, then you can use a task and call `Task.Result` to return your value. For example like this:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    var val = value.ToString();
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return val;
    });
    return task.Result;
}
```

For the scenario I used this code, I use two way binding to bind the `SelectedIndex` of a `ListView` to the `Text` of a `TextBox`, here is the demo:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:BlankPage6ViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <local:IndexToItemConverter x:Key="cvt" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="5" Height="50" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel and Model:

```
public class BlankPage6ViewModel
{
    public BlankPage6ViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<IDModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new IDModel { ID = i, Name = "Name " + i });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IDModel> MyItems { get; set; }
}

public class IDModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The whole converter is simple like this:

```
public class IndexToItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CONVERT");
        return Int32.Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var val = value.ToString();
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return val;
        });
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

Rendering image of this demo:
[image]

There is a very good blog for this scenario, you can have a look: [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Please do _NOT_ do this. It blocks your UI thread completely and stalls the app (you can even see it in the gif above). Never ever use Task.Result.
Better to have your setter raise PropertyChanged a second after the setter gets hit.

Comment: @dotMortend Good suggestion.